# msysGit Bash cannot escape its home directory?

Tags: windows, msysgit, git-bash

I start the msysGit Bash using the provided batch file (the one that simulates a Linux environment). Bash starts up in msysGit's home directory (on my flashdrive). I would like to leave this directory to go to my project's directory (also on my flashdrive). So, I enter "$ cd .." This has no effect at all. I type "$ ls" and I'm definitely still in the Git folder. I try "cd ~" which brings me to my user folder, but I can't get to the root directory of my flashdrive. How can I get there with msysGit Bash?

I cannot use git-cmd.bat because the computers at my school deny access to cmd.exe.
Alternative question: How can I run git-cmd without needing administrator permissions?

If there is another distributed-model version control system that works better on portable devices (especially on systems where cmd is restricted and I'm not an administrator), I'll gladly switch to it (if you know of one, please tell).

Comment: Can't just use "normal" msys itself? (I don't use git, but perhaps it is a chroot?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access the root directory of any drive by specify its driver letter:
(for instance)

```
cd /e
```

Comment: Ah!! Thank you very much! I have always been inept in the usage of any console, but now I know a little more.